# Падение производительности при разных конфигурациях запуска

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

Есть БД SQLite, в основной таблице примерно 3000 записей. При загрузке записей к ним догружаются данные из других таблиц. Данные загружаются с разными фильтрами по времени (UnixTimeStamp):

```
[Indexed]
public long TransDateStamp { get; set; }
```

- При запуске в режиме Debug - все работает нормально.
- В режиме Release - скорость падает.
- При запуске пакета Appx - опять все нормально
- При запуске загруженного приложения из магазина - скорость падает.

Замеры времени производил программно через TimeSpan, ниже таблица измерений на ПК и Мобильном телефоне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого есть идеи - почему такое происходит?

**UPD:** Причину в принципе выяснил, виновата галочка "Компилировать с использованием цепочки". Если ее выключить, то производительность конфигурации Release нормализуется. Однако, до сих пор не понятно, почему при установке из локального пакета работает нормально, а из магазина нет...

**UPD2** Если собрать пакет приложения без этой галочки, то в магазин его отправить не удастся, т.к. он не пройдет сертификацию "Supported API" - Error

**UPD3** Гугление по теме наводит на мысль что виноваты анонимные типы которые (если верить MSDN) имею *very poor perfomance* в среде .NET Native. Теперь вопрос в том как от них избавиться? например такой код:

```
var query = from item in Transaction.TransactionsHistory(Filter)
                        where !item.isDeleted
                        orderby item.Date descending, item.Created descending
                        group item by item.displayGroupName into g
                        select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };
```

С таким вот анонимным типом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD4** В общем никакие манипуляции не дали желаемого результата.

MSDN говорит:

> Avoid using anonymous types in LINQ queries on UWP. Deploying a UWP
>   application to the app store requires your application to be compiled
>   with .NET Native. Queries with anonymous types have poor performance
>   on .NET Native or may crash the application.

У себя в коде не использовал ни одного `anonymous` типа, начинаю грешить на `SQLiteWrapperUWP-PCL`. Пробовал заменить его на `BuildIt.Data.Sqlite` - получил проседание скорости еще в 1.5 раза. Буду пробовать EF7

Comment: На какой операции проседает, не пробовали найти? Профайлеры нынче более-менее правдивую картину выдают.

Comment: @Monk На всех запросах к БД. Как только включается галочка, происходит то что в таблице...

Comment: Всмысле, тупо sql запрос один и тот же дорожает в 2-4 раза? Не сталкивался, выглядит странно.

Comment: @Monk потому таблицу и приложил. Данные те же, код тот же, девайс тот же. Разница в галочке

Comment: @Monk по последнему UPD есть идеи?

Comment: Не уверен. Зачем вообще последний select, если groupby тоже самое и возвращает?

Comment: Ну, заведите тип явно. `class X { public string GroupName; public IEnumerable<Transaction> Items; }` или как-то так. И возвращайте `new X() { ... }`.

Comment: @VladD, так это сама группа, можно спокойно без класса обойтись пока.

Comment: @Monk оно то можно, но надо производительность поправить.

Comment: @Monk: Ну мало ли, может быть там ещё Select есть где-нибудь.

Comment: @Monk тут выходит самое узкое место. В этот список попадает 3К записей, потом он дополнительно обрабатывается и с него заполняется CollectionViewSource, завтра попробую явно обьявить переменную и замерить скорость...

Comment: @SYL: А спрофилировать на устройстве не получается?

Comment: @VladD на телефоне нет. Но по всем замерам\дебагам что я делал вывод следует что SQLiteWrapper очень плохо работает при компиляции в .NET Native

Comment: @SYL: В таком случае вам, возможно, имеет смысл обратиться к разработчикам `SQLiteWrapper` и узнать у них подробности проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, после долгих поисков, решение было найдено:

Для проекта использовался враппер который рекомендуется практически в каждой статье связанной с `UWP` и `SQLite`: [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) - который и являлся источником проблемы.

Эта библиотека является форком [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) - который показывает одинаковую скорость работы как в среде `CIL` так и в `.NET Native` (хотя в `CIL` незначительно уступает в скорости первому, что компенсируется очень быстрой работой в `.NET Native`).

**P.S.** EF7 - еще не готов для использования. Кишит багами, практически неработоспособен в среде .NET Native, хотя и показал крайне высокую скорость работы и удобство использования (по сравнению с предыдущими двумя библиотеками).

Comment: а что за предыдущие 2 библиотеки? 5 и 6 версии EF?

Comment: @nikita SQLite.Net-PCL и sqlite-net-pcl. EF 5 и 6 для UWP нету.